# In the category of uniform spaces, is the completion of a quotient map also a quotient map?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, quotient-spaces, uniform-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two Hausdorff uniform spaces. A surjective uniformly continuous map $f: X \to Y$ is a *quotient map* if for every map $g$ from $Y$ to a uniform space $Z$ such that $g \circ f$ is uniformly continuous, $g$ is uniformly continuous.

Let $\hat X$ and $\hat Y$ denote the completions of $X$ and $Y$ respectively, and let
$\hat f : \hat X \to \hat Y$ be the unique uniformly continuous extension of $f$.
Is $\hat f$ a quotient map?

If the answer is positive, a reference would be appreciated.